# How can I get click event when I click to primefaces commandbutton in jsf?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, commandbutton

I would like to know how to get click event from primefaces commandbutton ?
Here is my code about my problem:

JSF file:

```
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="TreeListFilter.js" target="head" />

     <script type="text/javascript">
        $ = jQuery;
        $(document).ready(
                function() {
                    $('#form\\:taniara2').treeListFilter(
                            '.ui-tree-container', 200);
                }
        );
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("123");
        $ = jQuery;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#form\\:aratani').click(function() {
                alert("456");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Original code is in here:
[FileTreeView](http://wiki.aiwsolutions.net/2014/03/13/filetreeview-plugin/)

Comment: My suggestion would be use a better documented plugin

Comment: Do you know any plugins for use in primefaces tree filtering and expanding tree ?

Comment: Use any, browser doesn't care what framework or langauge you use on server. tree plugins are not hard to find

Comment: I'm developing my project in java and using jsf primefaces so I need a tree that can be used in jsf

Comment: Huh? The browser only sees html , css and javascript. What difference does jsf make?

Comment: so do you know any tree example that has features such as filtering expanding ?

Comment: let google be your friend

Comment: you are very informative thank you, I also know google, I searched google then I asked here to get answer, I just want to know how to get class name in jsf to get it work on jquery

Comment: I have no idea what class you are referring to or how it would help in browser

Answer (score 0):

When I wrote below code my alert function worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("123");
    $ = jQuery;
    $(document).on('click',"#form\\:aratani",function() {
            alert("456");
    });
</script>
```